# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to achieve this outlook. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6COFI.png It's the first time I'm using provider. The same code worked well with a todo app. But I could not get to work the code for this app. I've tried to tweak with the code, but only in vain.

The error message is,  ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write: Provider.of(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: AddPlayersScreen(state:
_AddPlayersScreenState#da0e7) 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 242 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding ||
listen == false ||
debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:242:7)
#3      _AddPlayersScreenState.build. (package:badminton_app/screens/add_players_screen.dart:73:34)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
#5      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
#10     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
#11     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
#12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
#14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
#15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
#19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
#20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5) (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)

Handler: "onTap" Recognizer:   TapGestureRecognizer#65790 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
import 'package:badminton_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/model/player_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/model/players_data.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/widgets/check_cards.dart';

TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

class AddPlayersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddPlayersScreenState createState() => _AddPlayersScreenState();
}

class _AddPlayersScreenState extends State<AddPlayersScreen> {
  String newText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff07021A),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Text(
                'Add Players',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 400.0,
                height: 50.0,
                child: Divider(
                  height: 10.0,
                  color: Color(0xff525274),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(400.0, 70.0)),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Color(0xffA8A3BE),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffA8A3BE), fontSize: 20.0),
                  controller: _controller,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    newText = newValue;
                  },
                  enabled: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffix: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _controller.clear();
                      },
                      icon: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 13.0,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff939393),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.clear,
                          size: 25.0,
                          color: Color(0xff585179),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).changeString(newText);
                      },
                      icon: Container(
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: 50.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          )),
                    ),
                    hintText: "New member......",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                      color: Color(
                        0xffA199C6,
                      ),
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xff585179),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: PlayerList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


   
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/model/players.dart';

class PlayerData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Players> _playerData = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<Players> get playerData {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_playerData);
  }

  toggleSelect(Players players) {
    players.toggle();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get getLength {
    return playerData.length;
  }

  changeString(newString) {
    _playerData.add(Players(name: newString));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeString(Players player) {
    _playerData.remove(player);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}



import 'package:badminton_app/model/players_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/model/players.dart';

class CheckCards extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function callBack;
  CheckCards({this.name, this.isSelected = false, this.callBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 25.0,
            top: 17.0,
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: callBack,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),
                      color: Colors.yellow),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: isSelected
                        ? Icon(
                            Icons.brightness_1,
                            size: 30.0,
                            color: Color(0xff585179),
                          )
                        : Icon(
                            Icons.stop,
                            size: 30.0,
                            color: Color(0xff585179),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 80.0,
            top: 22.0,
            child: Text(
              'Sai Deepak',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      height: 70.0,
      width: 500.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? Color(0xff21213C) : Color(0xff585179),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
    );
  }
}



import 'package:badminton_app/model/players.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/model/players_data.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/widgets/check_cards.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:badminton_app/widgets/tile.dart';

class PlayerList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayerListState createState() => _PlayerListState();
}

class _PlayerListState extends State<PlayerList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PlayerData>(builder: (context, data, child) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final playo = data.playerData[index];
          return CheckCards(
            name: playo.name,
            isSelected: playo.isDone,
            callBack: () {
              data.toggleSelect(playo);
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: data.getLength,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Can somebody please help me with this. This thing is screwing up mind for days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: from the error I read it said: To fix, write: Provider.of(context, listen: false);

Comment: I cannot update my UI by adding that.

Comment: then call `setState((){})` after that code should rebuild the UI

Answer (score 2):

In onPressed () use

Provider.of(context, listen: false);

Check that you pass listen:false
You can you also setState if you change a local data

Comment:  It is so stressful to see, how a small error can bug your mind for days. Thanks man.

Comment: if the solution work with you Check the true answer in my answer above

Comment: Had the same error. Using @AhmedElsayed, fix it worked. Still I don't fully understand why it should be false though...